# Is the convex combination of an interior point and a boundary point also in the interior?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space, $D \subset X$ and $(D, \tau_{D})$ a topological space.  We are working on this subspace topology.

Suppose we have a closed convex set $C \subset D$, which has a non-empty interior, $C^{\mathrm{o}}$.

If $x \in \partial C$ and $y \in C^{\mathrm{o}}$, then for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, is $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in C^{\mathrm{o}}$?

I think this is true, but I am not sure how to prove it.  Both answers to this (especially the answer which is not accepted) [Closure of interior of closed convex set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287213/closure-of-interior-of-closed-convex-set) may be helpful.

Comment: Is $D$ a topological **vector** space?

Comment: No, $D$ is not.  In my setting, $D$ is a subset of $X$, which is a vector space, but $D$ does not contain the zero vector.

Comment: Your question does not make sense . In a general topological space there is no such thing as  a convex set.

Comment: True - I will fix that now.

Comment: Interior and boundary are taken wrt to the topology on $D$?

Comment: Yes, we are viewing $C$ as a subset of $D$ and working wrt the topology on $D$.

Answer (score 1):

The point $y$ is in the interior of $C$, hence for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, the $\varepsilon$-ball around $y$ is also in $C$. As $C$ is convex, the line from any point in the $\varepsilon$-ball to $x$ is also in $C$. The union of all these lines forms a kind of cone that is part of $C$. For any point on the line from $x$ to $y$ that is not $x$ itself a small ball around this point is inside this cone and thus in $C$. This proves that any point on this line apart from $x$ is not on the boundary of $C$.

Comment: This certainly seems like the correct way of going about proving it.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there a more rigorous way to show this. This kind of cone doesn't seem mathematically very solid to me, even though I understand the argument.

Comment: Hi Felix, actually I think this result may not be true.  There is also this answer which has 8 upvotes https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20473 which I think is not true too.  It says If $C$ is a convex subset of a topological space, and if $x\in \mathrm{int} C$ and $y\in \mathrm{cl} C$, then $[x,y)\subset \mathrm{int} C$ (where the half-open segment $[x,y)$ is a right-open convex combination).