# Convex combination of closure and interior is in interior of convex set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set that has nonempty interior.

Show: $y\in\mathrm{cl}C,\;x\in\mathrm{Int}C \; \implies\; \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in\mathrm{Int}C$

My attempt: The case $y\in\mathrm{Int}C$ is obvious, I am struggling with $y\in\partial C$, so $y$ on the boundary of $C$.

Comment: see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure/20473#20473

Comment: The answer sadly leaves my case as an exercise, so no. The other answers just prove $\dot{\overline{C}}=\dot{C}$, which would only recharacterize my problem.

Comment: well. what about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503970/is-the-convex-combination-of-an-interior-point-and-a-boundary-point-also-in-the?rq=1

Comment: This assumes that $C$ is closed..

Comment: This should give you an idea how to argue for $y\in C$, then generalize to $y \in cl \  C $.