# Interior and closed cover properties of the convex normed subsets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

## Task

Let C be a convex subset of a normed space X with a non-empty interior. Proove that the closure of the interior of C matches the closure of C. Proove that the interior of the closure of C matches the interior of C:

$$int\overline C = int C$$
$$\overline C = \overline{int C}$$

### We have to use the following:

Let $x \in \overline{C}$, and $x \notin intC$

From this follows:
$$intC \subset C$$
$$\overline{intC} \subset \overline{C}$$

## Attemp:

We can say that intC is open and convex, right?

**Theorem**: X is Banach space, C - open convex subspace of X, $x_0 \notin C => \exists f \in X^*,f \neq 0$, such that $f(x)< f(x_0) \forall x \in C$

Can we use this theorem to get all the limit points:
$$S = \{x \in \overline{C} : x \neq intC \}$$

Is the following correct:
$$\overline{intC} = intC \cup S$$

From which:
$$\overline C = \overline{int C}$$

## Question:

Guess this is not correct, can you please proove these statements and show me the the proof.

## Note:

The only potentially good thing I could do is maybe use the corollaries of Hahn-Banach. I think that is what I am assigned to be looking for(But maybe I have to use something else).

## EDIT:

What I understand by closed cover:

closed cover of a set А is intersection of all closed sets, containing A:

$$\overline{A}=\cap_i \overline{A_i}$$

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the standard term for what you called "closed cover" is "closure".

Comment: @DanielFischer Not sure I've made an edit, please check the update, there is an Edit seciont

Comment: I guess that should be "intersection" instead of "section" (literal translation from your language?), and the symbol $\cap$ instead of $\cup$ (typo). Then that is what usually is called the closure. (I suspect "closed cover" is also a literal translation.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, all correct

Comment: The first part is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287213/closure-of-interior-of-closed-convex-set). The question speaks of a closed convex set, but the answers do not assume that. Do you understand these answers?

Comment: @DanielFischer not sure what $C^o$ means, also not quite getting the calculations and not sure.. is p(t) making a line between $C^o$ and $\overline{}$

Comment: $C^{\circ}$ is another notation for the interior of $C$. Yes, $p(t)$ gives the line segment from $p$ to $c$.

Comment: For the second part the claim from Daniel Fischer’s link applied to $\overline{C}$ yields $\overline{C}=\overline{\operatorname{int} \overline{C}}=$ (by the first part) $\overline{\operatorname{int} C}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky theorem fixed, but I am not sure I quite understand the calculations in everything

Comment: What you don't understand in my arguments?

Comment: First, doesn't the link prove that $\overline{intC}=C$? we want $\overline{intC}=\overline{C}$ . The second top answer does not fit our use case for  $\overline{int\overline{C}}=\overline{intC}$, as it's described for topological vector spaces and it's not proved. Question: why is $\overline{C}=\overline{int\overline{C}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1, $\overline C = \overline{\text{int }C}:$ Let $x \in \text{int }C, y\in C.$ Then there is an open ball $B=B(x,r)\subset C.$ Since $C$ is convex, $tB+(1-t)y\subset C$ for all $t\in [0,1].$ Note that if $t\in (0,1],$ then $tB+(1-t)y$ is an open ball lying in $C.$ Thus the open set

$$U= \bigcup_{t\in (0,1]} tB+(1-t)y \subset C.$$

Because $[x,y)\subset U,$ we see see that $y$ is the limit of a sequence in $U \subset \text{int }C.$ Therefore $\overline C \subset \overline{\text{int }C}.$ Since the reverse containment is obvious, we have the result.

Problem 2, $\text{int }C =\text{int }\overline C:$ Write $\overline C = \text{int }C\cup \partial C.$ Let $x\in\text{int }C, y\in \partial C.$

Claim: For $s>1,$ $x+s(y-x)\notin \overline C.$ (Thus $y$ is the "last point" in $\overline C$ on the ray from $x$ in the direction of $y.$)

Proof: Suppose this is false. Then for some $s>1,$ $z= x+s(y-x)\in \overline C.$ Now $y\in [x,z],$ so there exists $t\in (0,1)$ such that $y=tx+(1-t)z.$ Because $z\in \overline C,$ there exists a sequence $z_n$ in $C$ such that $z_n\to z.$

Choose $B=B(x,r)$ such that $B\subset \text{int }C.$ Then $B_n =tB+(1-t)z_n \subset \text{int }C$ for all $n.$ Note that the center of $B_n$ is $tx+(1-t)z_n$ and its radius is $tr.$ Here's the thing: $y\in B_n$ for large $n.$  To see this, use $y=tx+(1-t)z$ in the inequality $|y-(tx+(1-t)z_n)|<tr.$

Thus $y\in \text{int }C.$ But that's a contradiction, as $y\in \partial C,$ a set disjoint from $\text{int }C.$ This proves the claim.

This implies no open ball centered at $y$ is contained in $\overline C.$ It follows that no point on $\partial C$ can be in $\text{int }\overline C.$ This gives the desired result.

Comment: In the 1st part it's said that there is a sequence for which y is a limit. what is that sequence ?

Comment: @Harton $(1/n)x +(1-1/n)y, n=1,2,\dots$ will work.

Comment: we get $C \subset \overline{intC}$  Do we get $\overline{C} \subset \overline{intC}$ from it and why ? it's obvious that $C \subset \overline{C} $ but why is $\overline{C} \subset \overline{intC}$

Comment: $\overline C$ is the smallest closed set containing $C$ and $\overline {\text{int }C}$ is a closed set containing $C.$ Therefore $\overline C \subset \overline {\text{int }C}.$

Comment: I am not sure I understand the sequence Idea ... can I say there is a seq $\{y_i\}:=(1/n)x+(1-1/n)y$ and limyi =y ?

Comment: I showed the half open interval $[x,y)$ is contained in the interior of $C.$ The sequence $(1/n)x+(1-1/n)$ lies in $[x,y)$ and converges to $y.$

Comment: That should be $(1/n)x+(1-1/n)y$ above