# Approximate a metric on a finite set by one having rational distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Let $(X,d)$ be a finite metric space, and let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. In this question I would like to understand

> how to show in detail the existence of a metric $\tilde{d}$ on $X$ that is "$\varepsilon$-close to $d$":
> \begin{align}
> |\tilde{d}(x,y)-d(x,y)|\leq\varepsilon,\qquad\forall x,y\in X
> \end{align}
> and "has rational distance":
> \begin{align}
> \tilde{d}(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q},\qquad\forall x,y\in X
> \end{align}

My motivation comes from the encounter with the Gromov-Hausdorff metric space $(\mathcal{M},d_{GH})$. In the proof of separability of $(\mathcal{M},d_{GH})$, the countable dense subset is given by the collection of all such finite metric spaces with rational distance (up to isometry). The idea is that any compact metric space can be "approximated" by a finite metric space, but the collection of all finite metric spaces (up to isometry) may still be uncountable (due to the many choices of metric on the same underlying set), so we restrict ourselves to those that have rational distance. Then we need to make sure that any metric on a finite space can be "approximated" by one that has rational distance. It is here where I am unable to spell out the detail.

My attempt was a constructive proof: Denote $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$, and denote $d(x_i,x_j)=|x_ix_j|$. Clearly, the interval $\big(|x_ix_j|-\varepsilon,|x_ix_j|+\varepsilon\big)$ always contains some rational number $q_{ij}$. The problem is how to choose them in order to make the triangle inequality
\begin{align}
q_{ij}\leq q_{ik}+q_{jk}
\end{align}
holds, so that we can define $\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)=\tilde{d}(x_j,x_i)=q_{ij}$. For $i<j$ we always have $|x_ix_j|>0$, so I was thinking of diminishing it a little to get $q_{ij}$ while enlarging $|x_ix_k|$, $|x_jx_k|$ a little to get $q_{ik},q_{jk}$, but this seems not to work because the same $q_{ij}$ needs to appear in both sides of the triangle inequality (e.g. $q_{12}$ is on the L.H.S. of $q_{12}\leq q_{13}+q_{23}$ while on the R.H.S. of $q_{23}\leq q_{12}+q_{13}$).

Any comment, hint or answer is welcome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since there are finitely many points there are finitely many distances between points. Construct a ball around each point with radius less than half the minimum distance between points. This ensures the balls don't overlap. After that you can choose an appropriate rational in each ball and the triangle inequality will be inherited from the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sorry but may I know what do you mean by "an appropriate rational in each ball"? As far as I know, for a finite metric space, a ball $B(x,r)$ with $r>0$ sufficiently small is essentially the singleton $\{x\}$ itself...

Comment: Hint: Prove first that the set of all metrics on a finite set forms a convex cone with nonempty interior. Then argue that rational vectors are dense in every such cone.

Comment: @Hopfeccentric I mean some rational approximation of the real distance. For example you could truncate the decimal expansion to a sufficient degree of accuracy as to conform with the $\epsilon$ condition.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But the ball will still be singletons though. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm guessing that you are having a picture of points sitting in $\mathbb{R}^d$, in which case the choosing of rational points or the rational approximation make perfect sense, but my finite set is not assumed to be a priori in any bigger ambient space though.

Comment: @Hopfeccentric they will still be singletons but the distances can be rationalized with respect to the metric. The ball is to ensure you don't accidentally define it in a way that includes a second point which can cause complications. If we chose a rational point in some ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ this would be equivalent to changing the underlying set which as you noted is not reasonable in this context. Looking back I can see I worded things badly. Sorry if it caused any confusion.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I see. Thanks so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps of the proof, all quite elementary.

1. Suppose $X$ has cardinality $n$. Then each pseudometric on $X$ is encoded by a vector in ${\mathbb R}^N$, $N=n(n-1)/2$. The semipositivity conditions and triangle inequalities satisfied by the pseudometrics amount to a system of nonstrict linear (homogeneous) inequalities $f_k({\mathbf v})\ge 0$, $k=1,...,K$. Thus, the space of possible pseudometrics on $X$ is a closed convex cone $C$ in ${\mathbb R}^N$. Let $C^\circ\subset C$ denote the subset given by the strict inequalities $f_k({\mathbf v})> 0$, $k=1,...,K$. Then each vector in $C^\circ$ corresponds to a genuine metric on $X$ and $C^\circ$ is open in ${\mathbb R}^N$.
2. Show that the cone $C$ has nonempty interior. For instance, the discrete metric belongs to $C^\circ$, which is contained in the interior of $C$ (in fact, it equals to the interior of $C$ but we will not need this).
3. Use the fact that each closed convex subset of ${\mathbb R}^N$ (with nonempty interior) is the closure of its interior. (This is true in much greater generality of convex subsets in topological vector spaces, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287213/closure-of-interior-of-closed-convex-set).)
4. Lastly, use density of rational points in the interior of $C$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but I still have some questions. 1.  I'm fine with Step 1,3,4, but how to prove Step 2? The discrete metric is encoded by the vector $v=(1,\ldots,1)$. To show that it's an interior point I'd need to find an open ball $B(v,r)$ such that any vector in this ball has entries satisfying the system of inequalities, but I'm not sure how this is done. I'd think that this is the same difficulty as described in my post above.

Comment: 2. Some texts define a cone by requiring whenever $d$ is a metric then so is $\lambda d$ for all $\lambda\geq 0$,  but $0d$ is definitely not a metric, since distinct points will not have nonzero distance. If $\lambda$ is only required to be $>0$ then this problem disappears, but then the cone will not be closed though...

Comment: 3. May I know how do you come up with this proof? I've never thought of viewing the space of metrics as a convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^N$ before...

Comment: First, the closed cone $C$ I defined (by nonstrict inequalities) encodes not only metrics but also pseudometrics. Thus, $0$ is not a problem. The subset $C^\circ\subset C$ (the "open cone"), defined by strict inequalities, consists entirely of metrics. It is obviosly an open subset (since it is the intersection of finitely many open half-spaces).  For the discrete metric on $X$ all triangle inequalities are strict, hence, it lies in the open cone $C^\circ$, hence, is an interior point of $C$. In my proof shows that one can approximate every psedumetric on $X$ by rational metrics.

Comment: As for the last question, I am sure I saw it elsewhere and many times. But how else would you describe the totality of all metrics on a set? I think, this is the most natural idea.

Comment: Ah yes the set satisfying the *strict* triangle inequalities are open half-spaces... silly me. Thanks so much for the answer. For the last question, I'm asking it because, as seen from my post above, I'm tackling the problem by focusing on the given metric alone, while your approach is looking instead at the totality of all metrics (kind of "local vs global"?), which I didn't manage to think of before despite knowing that a "global" approach is often very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Moishe Kohan's answer (thanks for the answer), but I reckon it doesn't hurt to supply an alternative solution. The following approach is inspired by the discussion above with CyclotomicField, though it may be slightly different from his/her original idea, and perhaps it may look less elegant.

---

I shall construct $\tilde{d}$ by a direct modification of $d$. First, let me begin with an informal discussion. By drawing pictures of triangles, it seems intuitively clear that as long as $r>0$ is chosen to satisfies
\begin{align}
r<\frac{1}{2}\min_{1\leq i<j\leq N}d(x_i,x_j)
\end{align}
then if we modify by choosing $\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)$ to be a rational number $r$-close to $d(x_i,x_j)$, then the picture still looks like a triangle and $\tilde{d}$ could possibly be a metric. However, there is a small catch here. When we're drawing a picture of triangle, we have implicitly restricted ourselves to the case where the triangle inequalities on any three distinct points are all *strict*. However, we know that this may not always be the case; the triangle inequality is allowed to hold as an equality. In this case, no matter how small $r>0$ is chosen, it is always possible for a triangle inequality failing to hold for some three points.

> For example, consider $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ with
> \begin{align}
> d(x_1,x_2)=d(x_2,x_3)=1,\qquad d(x_1,x_3)=2
> \end{align}
> If we now choose
> \begin{align}
> \tilde{d}(x_1,x_2)=\tilde{d}(x_2,x_3)=1-q,\qquad\tilde{d}(x_1,x_3)=2+q
> \end{align}
> (where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $0<q<r$) then it is indeed true that $\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)$ is always $r$-close to $d(x_i,x_j)$, but it also follows that
> \begin{align}
> \tilde{d}(x_1,x_3)>\tilde{d}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{d}(x_2,x_3)
> \end{align}
> no matter how small the $r$ (hence $q$) is chosen. (Of course, for such three-point metric space, it is clear how to modify the metric correctly. What I wish to emphasize is that simply choosing $\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)$ to be any rational number that is $r$-close to $d(x_i,x_j)$ does *not always* work.)

---

This motivates me to separate the problem into two cases. The first one is where the triangle inequalities on three distinct points are all *strict*. Since the metric space is finite, the number of triangle inequalities is also finite. Thus in this case, we have
\begin{align}
\delta:=\min\big\{d(x_i,x_k)+d(x_k,x_j)-d(x_i,x_j):1\leq i,j,k\leq N\text{ are all distinct}\big\}
\end{align}
is always positive. Now we may choose $r>0$ to satisfies
\begin{align}
r\leq\min\left\{\epsilon,\frac{\delta}{3}\right\}
\end{align}
Then, using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, for each $1\leq i<j\leq N$ we choose a rational number $q_{ij}$ in the open interval $\big(d(x_i,x_j)-r,d(x_i,x_j)+r\big)$. Define $\tilde{d}$ by
\begin{align}
\tilde{d}(x_i,x_i)&=0,\qquad\forall 1\leq i\leq N \\
\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)=\tilde{d}(x_j,x_i)&=q_{ij},\qquad\forall 1\leq i<j\leq N
\end{align}
To prove that $\tilde{d}$ is a metric on $X$, the only nontrivial thing remains to show is the triangle inequality. Due to our choice of $r$, we see that for each distinct $1\leq i,j,k\leq N$
\begin{align}
\tilde{d}(x_i,x_j)
&<d(x_i,x_j)+r \\
&\leq d(x_i,x_j)+\delta-2r \\
&\leq d(x_i,x_k)-r+d(x_k,x_j)-r \\
&<\tilde{d}(x_i,x_k)+\tilde{d}(x_k,x_j) \tag{*}
\end{align}
and the triangle inequality clearly holds if (at least) two of $i,j,k$ are equal. Hence, $\tilde{d}$ is a metric. It is clear that $\tilde{d}$ is $\epsilon$-close to $d$ and has rational distance.

---

The second case is that for some set of three distinct points in $X$, some triangle *equality* holds on them. In this case, the strategy is to first modify the metric into $d_{*}$ which belongs to the previous case. However, we need to be a little bit more careful. We shall first modify the smallest distance, then proceed in the ascending order. Formally, let
\begin{align}
S:=\left\{d(x_i,x_j):i\neq j\text{, and }d(x_i,x_j)=d(x_i,x_k)+d(x_k,x_j)\text{ for some }k\neq i,j\right\}
\end{align}
After reindexing if necessary, wlog suppose $d(x_1,x_2)=\min S$. Then there is some $k_1\neq 1,2$ such that
\begin{align}
d(x_1,x_2)=d(x_1,x_{k_1})+d(x_{k_1},x_2)
\end{align}
Modify $d$ into $d_1$ by
\begin{align}
d_1(x_1,x_{k_1}):&=d(x_1,x_{k_1})+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
d_1(x_{k_1},x_2):&=d(x_{k_1},x_2)+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
d_1(x,y):&=d(x,y) & \text{otherwise}
\end{align}
Then $d_1$ is $(\epsilon/2)$-close to $d$ and has *one less* triangle equality. If we define $S_1$ in the same way as $S$ but by using $d_1$, then we see that
\begin{align}
S_1=S\setminus\{d(x_1,x_2)\}=S\setminus\{d_1(x_1,x_2)\}
\end{align}
If $S_1=\emptyset$, then we are done: Choose $d_{*}=d_1$. Otherwise, we repeat the process. Note that by the minimality of $d(x_1,x_2)$ in $S$, we have
\begin{align}
d(x_1,x_{k_1}),d(x_{k_1},x_2)\notin S
\end{align}
Let $d_1(x_{i_1},x_{j_1})=d(x_{i_1},x_{j_1})=\min S_1$. Then there is a $k_2\neq i_1,j_1$ such that
\begin{align}
d_1(x_{i_1},x_{j_1})=d_1(x_{i_1},x_{k_2})+d_1(x_{k_2},x_{j_1}) 
\end{align}
Modify $d_1$ into $d_2$ by
\begin{align}
d_2(x_{i_1},x_{k_2}):&=d_1(x_{i_1},x_{k_2})+\frac{\epsilon}{4}, & \text{if } \{x_{i_1},x_{k_2}\}\neq\{x_1,x_{k_1}\},\{x_{k_1},x_2\} \\
d_2(x_{k_2},x_{j_1}):&=d_1(x_{k_2},x_{j_1})+\frac{\epsilon}{4}, & \text{if } \{x_{k_2},x_{j_1}\}\neq\{x_1,x_{k_1}\},\{x_{k_1},x_2\} \\
d_2(x,y):&=d_1(x,y)
\end{align}
We have imposed the conditions to ensure that $d_1(x_1,x_{k_1})$ and $d_1(x_{k_1},x_2)$ will not be further modified again. Then $d_2$ has one less triangle equality than $d_1$, and remains to be $(\epsilon/2)$-close to $d$.

Continue this process. It must end in finite number of steps, and we obtain $d_n$ for some $n\leq N$. Choose $d_{*}=d_n$. Then $d_{*}$ satisfies no any triangle equality on any set of three distinct points of $X$, so we are back to the first case. It then tells us that there is a metric $\tilde{d}$ with rational distance such that $\tilde{d}$ is $(\epsilon/2)$-close to $d_{*}$. Hence, $\tilde{d}$ is $\epsilon$-close to $d$.

> To illustrate, let me provide an example. Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and suppose
> \begin{align}
> d(x_1,x_2)=d(x_2,x_3)=d(x_3,x_4)=1,\qquad
> d(x_1,x_3)=d(x_2,x_4)=2,\qquad d(x_1,x_4)=3
> \end{align}
> Then $S=\big\{d(x_1,x_3),d(x_2,x_4),d(x_1,x_4)\big\}$.
>
> 1. The 1st step deals with
>    \begin{align}
>    d(x_1,x_3)=d(x_1,x_2)+d(x_2,x_3)
>    \end{align}
>    Define $d_1(x_1,x_2)=1+\epsilon/2$ and $d_1(x_2,x_3)=1+\epsilon/2$, and $d_1(x,y)=d(x,y)$ otherwise.
> 2. The 2nd step  deals with
>    \begin{align}
>    d_1(x_2,x_4)&=d(x_2,x_4) \\
>    &=d(x_2,x_3)+d(x_3,x_4) \\
>    &=d_1(x_2,x_3)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}+d_1(x_3,x_4)
>    \end{align}
>    Since $\{x_2,x_3\}$ has already appeared in Step 1, we shall only modify $d_1(x_3,x_4)$. Define $d_2(x_3,x_4):=1+\frac{\epsilon}{4}$, and $d_2(x,y)=d_1(x,y)$ otherwise.
> 3. The last step deals with
>    \begin{align}
>    d_2(x_1,x_4)=d_2(x_1,x_2)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}+d_2(x_2,x_4)
>    \end{align}
>    Since $\{x_1,x_2\}$ has already appeared in the previous steps, we shall only modify $d_2(x_2,x_4)$. Define $d_3(x_2,x_4)=d_2(x_2,x_4)+\epsilon/6$ and $d_3(x,y)=d_2(x,y)$ otherwise. (Note: We can also start alternatively with
>    \begin{align}
>    d_2(x_1,x_4)=d_2(x_1,x_3)+d_2(x_3,x_4)-\frac{\epsilon}{4}. 
>    \end{align}
>    In this case, set $d_3(x_1,x_3)=d_2(x_1,x_3)-\epsilon/6$. )
>
> As a result, with $d_{*}=d_3$, we have
> \begin{align}
> d_{*}(x_1,x_2)=d_{*}(x_2,x_3)&=1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
> d_{*}(x_3,x_4)&=1+\frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
> d_{*}(x_1,x_3)&=2 \\
> d_{*}(x_2,x_4)&=2+\frac{\epsilon}{6} \\
> d_{*}(x_1,x_4)&=3
> \end{align}
> One can now check manually that $d_{*}$ satisfies *strict* triangle inequalities on every set of three distinct points.

---

Remark: It may be good to compare this solution to Moishe Kohan's answer.

1. Taking a closer look back at $(*)$, we see that the modification in the  1st case *preserves* strict triangle inequalities. This reflects the fact that the set $C^{\circ}$ of all metrics on $X$ satisfying strict triangle inequalities (on every set of distinct three points) is open (by suitably endowing the set of all (pseudo)metrics on $X$ a topology). This corresponds to Step 2 in his/her answer. See also the comment under the answer.
2. The 2nd case shows that every metric on $X$ can be approximated by one that satisfies strict triangle inequalities. In other words, every metric is in the closure of the open set $C^{\circ}$. This corresponds partly to Step 3 in his/her answer.

Hence, it seems that the two approaches are based on the same underlying structure of the space of all metrics on $X$.